# Error al ejecutar el código (Java)

Tags: java

LLevo un buen rato desesperado intentando arreglar mi código, pero por alguna razón no se ejecuta nada. Cabe recalcar que el programa no está terminado, pero cumpliendo lo que actualmente está escrito no funciona. Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar. Gracias!
Aquí el código:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ParesNones {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ParesNones p1 = new ParesNones();
        p1.leerTeclado();
        p1.paresnones();
    }
    int a;
    int b;
    int numero;
    String pares;
    public void leerTeclado() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Introduce un numero:");
        a = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Introduce un segundo numero:");
        b = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("¿Quieres ver los pares o los impares?");
        pares = scan.next();
        scan.close();

    }
    public void paresnones() {
        if (a > b) {
            for (numero = a; numero >= b; numero = numero - 1) {
                if (numero % 2 == 0 && pares == "pares") {
                    System.out.println(numero);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Esto es lo que ejecuto:

```
Introduce un numero:
10
Introduce un segundo numero:
2
¿Quieres ver los pares o los impares?
pares
```

**Fin de la ejecución**
Como se ve, se para ahí y no hace nada más.

Comment: Prueba con `pares = nextLine()` en vez de `next()`.

Comment: Trata de de debuggear tu código, es decir, ir ejecutando línea por línea y ver el flujo de tu código con el valor de tus variables. Generalmente es con F7, pero es depende del IDE que utilices.

Comment: Antes del IF , pon `System.out.println(pares);` y muestranos el valor.

Comment: Introduce un numero:
10
Introduce un segundo numero:
2
¿Quieres ver los pares o los impares?
pares
pares

Answer (score 1, accepted):

en el código que has pasado he visto que estas comparando un String usando "==". Para comparar los valores de un String debes usar el método ".equals("pares")".

Para comparar valores de Strings siempre debes usar el método equals, ya que sino estarás comprobando su referencia en memoria y no su valor.

Te paso el código con el equals:

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class ParesNones {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ParesNones p1 = new ParesNones();
        p1.leerTeclado();
        p1.paresnones();
    }
    int a;
    int b;
    int numero;
    String pares;
    public void leerTeclado() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Introduce un numero:");
        a = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Introduce un segundo numero:");
        b = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("¿Quieres ver los pares o los impares?");
        pares = scan.next();
        scan.close();

    }
    public void paresnones() {
        if (a > b) {
            for (numero = a; numero >= b; numero = numero - 1) {
                if (numero % 2 == 0 && pares.equals("pares")) {
                    System.out.println(numero);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Una de las cosas más importante cuando empiezas a programar es poder identificar que está ocurriendo, para ello, en este caso, creo que te vendría bien poner prints dentro del método paresnones , por ejemplo mostrando los valores de las variables a y b , el resultado de la condición a>b .... Todo lo que pienses que te puede ayudar.